# find what is supported by value_specs for an OpenStack resource

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-heat

I am working with OpenStack and HOT.
To know about supported resource types, i can visit [Template Guide](https://docs.openstack.org/heat/queens/template_guide/).

But it doesn't document what keywords does value_specs property support. Can someone guide me to correct documentation?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm facing the same problem now.